# Twitter Bootstrap - Perform action on tab "shown" event

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I need to "reset" some page information based on the selected tab in a bootstrap jQuery tab section.

The docs show this event, which is exactly what I need: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown', function (e) {
  e.target // activated tab
  e.relatedTarget // previous tab
})
```

I need to get the 'href' attribute of the `e.Target` and `e.relatedTarget`, which uniquely identify those 2 tabs and the 2 tab-content panes they are linked to.

Here's my problem: the `e` object is some object that I'm not expecting or used to.  I can't use any of the jQuery methods like `e.target.attr('href')` -- all the normal jquery methods I'm used to are gone.   I tried accessing it like a raw object attribute -- `e.href` , and got `https://127.0.0.1/test?action=view#tab-a"` not `#tab-a`

I can code a workaround with this - but I'm clearly doing something wrong.  There should be an easy way to directly get `#tab-a` from `e.target` -- but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Note that in Bootstrap 3, we need to use shown.bs.tab instead

Comment: With bootstrap 3 this should be `on('shown.bs.tab'` instead of `on('shown'`.

Comment: Since `e.target` give you this `https://127.0.0.1/test?action=view#tab-a` how you manage it to work? because this still no working, eg. `$("https://127.0.0.1/test?action=view#tab-a")` will return `undefined` or `Syntax error, unrecognized expression...`???

Comment: my solution was `e.target.hash` that retrieve the id of the panel `#tab-a`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try `$(e.target).attr('href')` instead.

Comment: Thank you SO much.  That was the exact answer.

Answer (score 5):

Late to the party by here is my take:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {

    e.currentTarget ...

});
```

e.currentTarget is the current anchor just clicked

Comment: Thanks a lot!!
we were upgrading our project in to bootstrap3 from bootstrap2 and it got fixed!!!

Answer (score 1):

If someone needs to know which **tab index** is currently selected without manually count it in DOM.

**Use case:** when #hrefs are updated dynamically and you can relay on tab index.

jQuery function [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) returns *integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery object relative to its sibling elements*.

```
var el = jQuery('#some .thing'); // some DOM node that contains tab html structure
var tab_list = el.find('.tabbable').first().find('a[data-toggle="tab"]');
// event namespace ".bs.tab" is important in some versions of Bootstrap 
tab_list.on('shown.bs.tab', function(e){

    // zero based index
    // jQuery function `.index()` returns zero-based DOM "order" index
    tab_index = $(e.target).parent().index();

    // store this index to cookie or somwhere
    // so that you can show that tab again when user comes back to page
    // or makes a page refresh (F5)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

These all should work.

1. `$(e.target).attr('href');`
2. `e.target.hash;`
3. `$(this).attr('href');`
4. `this.hash`