# Twitter Bootstrap tab shown event NOT firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

The following code is not working even after the required JS files are loaded. There is no error thrown. I'm doing this because the codemirror codepane does not directly load the code when there are tabs present in a page. Any fix?

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    console.log("Tab Shown");
    $('.CodeMirror').each(function (i, el) {
        el.CodeMirror.refresh();
    });
});
```

Comment: @JqueryKing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20705905/bootstrap-3-jquery-event-for-active-tab-change

Comment: @A.Wolff - Oh i newly learned

Comment: Are the tabs being inserted or replaced at any point? If the elements are being altered, the selector may not be finding them or may find previous instances that are no longer in the page. You may need to [delegate the event binding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110934/direct-vs-delegated-jquery-on).

Comment: The code you've included [works just fine](http://www.bootply.com/iNqWXTQ2QL). The problem lies elsewhere.