# Bootstrap 3 jquery event for active pill change

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

My goal is to overload Bootstrap nav pall click event, and I was happy to come across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20705905/bootstrap-3-jquery-event-for-active-tab-change)

I've modified the code the following way to make it work for pills, but I'm helpless to understand why it doesn't work.

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills" id="orders_tab">
                <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#orders_for_today">Текущие</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#orders_sent_to_vendors">Ожидающие</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#inventories">Остатки</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#sales">Продажи</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#sales_aggregate">Аггрегированные продажи</a></li>
                <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                      Прочее <span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="#orders_products">Продукты</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

JS

```
$('a[data-toggle="pill"]').on('shown.bs.pill', function (e) {
        var target = $(e.target).attr("href") // activated tab
        alert(target);
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Bootstrap nav-pills aka is a styling component not an js component. So data-toggle will be `data-toggle="tab"`.

Update Fiddle for your code [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cqfav1ky/)

```
data-toggle="tab"
```

only change required.

-Help :)

Answer (score 5):

Bootstrap pills and tabs use same javascript. Just the `.nav-pills` instead of `.nav-tabs` is different.

Replace the `data-toggle="pill"` with `data-toggle="tab"` everywhere and should work.

Comment: @EdgarNavasardyan yes