# Bootstrap data-toggle="tab" change/click not being recognized by JQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap `nav` set as `nav-pills` and trying to capture each time a tab is clicked using JQuery.

I cannot get the JQuery function to recognize each click.

I have a JSFiddle with the code I am using but cannot get the `alert` or `console.log` to fire - nothing appears:
https://jsfiddle.net/dzeller44/fctxwwy0/

I followed this post:
[Bootstrap 3 jquery event for active tab change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20705905/bootstrap-3-jquery-event-for-active-tab-change)

I appreciate the help.

Comment: you can mark the answer as correct if it worked for you so others having the same problem also get benefit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it needs to be `<a data-toggle="tab"` instead of `<a data-toggle="pill"` or change the `jquery` section from `$('a[data-toggle="tab"]')` to `$('a[data-toggle="pill"]')` see the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/buttflattery/fctxwwy0/2/) here.